# How to make a 3 column layout fill 100% width?

Tags: layout, html

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mYkjQ/

How do I make div2 + Button2 fill the rest of the window width?

Thank you.

**CSS**

```
td { border:solid 1px #000; float:left; }

#div1 { width:30%; border:solid 1px #000; float:left; }
#div2 { border:solid 1px #000; float:left; }
#div3 { width:30%; border:solid 1px #000; float:right; }

#Button1 { width:100% }
#Button2 { width:100% }
#Button3 { width:100% }
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="div1">
    <button id="Button1">Button 1</button>
</div>
<div id="div2">
    <button id="Button2">Button 2</button>
</div>
<div id="div3">
    <button id="Button3">Button 3</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way to do it is to float all 3 div-s to left, and remove the border because on some browsers it would break because of that 1 pixel.

If you really need the border then do this:

```
<style type="text/css">
    #div1, #div3 { float:left; width:30%; }
    #div2 { float:left; width:40%; }
    #subdiv1, #subdiv2, #subdiv3 { border:solid 1px #000; }
    #Button1, #Button2, #Button3 { width:100% }
</style>

<div id="div1">
    <div id="subdiv1">
        <button id="Button1">Button 1</button>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="div2">
    <div id="subdiv2">
        <button id="Button2">Button 2</button>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="div3">
    <div id="subdiv3">
        <button id="Button3">Button 3</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Edit1: [jsfiddle for testing](http://jsfiddle.net/aFMrL/) -> change the wrapper width to see that is scales to any width without breaking ...

Answer (score 1):

```
#div2 { border:solid 1px #000; float:left; width:40%; }
```

set width:40% to div2, don't forget to remove the border

Answer (score 0):

Check it out : http://jsfiddle.net/thilakar/mYkjQ/3/

I have done with approx calculation. i hope this may useful for you

Comment: This is not working. When you put the whole HTML into another div that 400px or smaller, then the last div is rendered below the other two as the 29.6% is still too big compared to the 1px border ...

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div id="div1">
    <button id="Button1">Button 1</button>
</div>
<div id="div2">
    <div id="div2a">
        <button id="Button2">Button 2</button>
    </div>
    <div id="div2b">
    <button id="Button3">Button 3</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#div1 { width:30%; border:solid 1px #000; float:left; }
#div2 { margin-left: 30.3% }
#div2a { width:49.3%; border:solid 1px #000; float: left }
#div2b { width:49.3%; border:solid 1px #000; float:right; }


#Button1 { width:100% }
#Button2 { width:100% }
#Button3 { width:100% }
```